# Find a list of items between 2 listboxes vb.net

Tags: vb.net, find

i want to check for each item in list box if item exist then add it to listbox3

```
for each item in listbox2.items
if listbox1.items.contains (item) then
listbox3.item.add (item)
end if
next
```

but it is very slow if there is way to search for list of items in listbox at once?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the **Intersect** method to get all the items they both contain. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx

It would look something like. Code below is untested.

```
 For Each item in listbox2.items.Intersect(listbox1.items)
        listbox3.item.add (item)
    Next
```

**EDIT:** So after looking at it, it seems items is an objectcollection which doesn't contain intersect. To get around that you can try.

```
For Each item in listbox2.items.Cast(Of Enumerable).Intersect(listbox1.items.Cast(Of Enumerable))
            listbox3.item.add (item)
        Next
```

Not sure how fast that will be though

Answer (score 0):

Unless each Listbox's collection of items is of a large magnitude, I don't see anything wrong with that approach (besides the minor coding errors).

Comment: it looks fast when you have few items in listbox2 but if you have more then 90 thousand items in both listboxes then it is very slow .

Comment: "if you have more then 90 thousand items in both" - yes, this will be slow. Perhaps placing IDs of each item into a Dictionary object and manipulating that to find matches would be faster, but I'm not familiar enough with what `Contains()` is doing "under-the-hood" to know if that's more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I created a list of 90,000 strings and this worked instantly:

```
ListBox3.DataSource = ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of IEnumerable).Intersect(ListBox2.Items.Cast(Of IEnumerable)).ToList
```